# Particles js in footer adds 3px space below footer

Tags: css, footer, particles.js

I'm having a slight problem with a footer containing particles.js. Whenever particle.js is added to the footer a 3px white space appears below the footer. This doesn't happen when particles.js is not in the footer, so it has to be directly related to particles.js (or the css applied to it).

I've created a mock up in jsfiddle, one shows the problem with particles.js and another shows the problem gone when particles.js is removed.

With particles.js: http://jsfiddle.net/hsy8jbwc/2/

Without particles.js: http://jsfiddle.net/hsy8jbwc/3/

```css
    #footer {position: relative; bottom: 0; width: 100%; height: 60px; line- 
    height: 60px; background-color: transparent}
    #footer .row {display:flex; align-items:center; justify-content: space- 
    around;}
    #footer-particles {position: absolute; height: 100%; width: 100%; background- 
    color: salmon; z-index: -1;}
```

```html
    <footer id="footer">
       <div id="footer-particles"></div>
       <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
             <span class="text-muted">FOOTER</span>
          </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
```

Comment: I don't know, but on Firefox the space is much larger. Maybe that's a clue.

Comment: @MrLister canvas adds whitespace exactly like image do, due to alignment

Comment: @TemaniAfif I was trying to say, in Firefox the space below the footer is larger than in Chrome, all else being the same.

Comment: *facepalm* Thank you for pointing out it's due to the cancas. Would've never thought of that.