# Why is there still a small margin on the footer?

Tags: javascript, html, css, particles.js

I was tinkering a little bit with particles.js, so i did this in html:

```
<div id="particles-js"></div>
```

and then this in css:

```
*{
    margin: 0%;
    padding: 0%;

}

#particles-js{

    background-color: rgb(169, 214, 169);
}
```

But at the bottom of the page there is still a little bit whitespace - around 3px - why is that? I added a screenshot because i don't know if it would work if i upload it on codepen with the cdn and all. I mean it probably would, but i'm a noob and a screenshot is faster and much more convenient for now:

[image: Full Screen]

Strangely, the whitespace seems only to be there if the browser window is maximized:

[image]

Well, hey, thanks for your help folks! I hope i have articulated my question well enough, but please tell me if not, and what i could do better in future questions, because there will surely be more of them!

Comment: did you tried to give your page a height? In CSS `height: 100vh;` makes your content take the hegiht of the viewport.

Comment: Seems that others had the same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50975645/particles-js-in-footer-adds-3px-space-below-footer?noredirect=1&lq=1 . Here's another instance, this one with a solution; looks like you'd have to add the CSS to the #particles-js declaration: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53715659/expand-particles-js-to-background

Comment: there is a canvas element created by particule.js .. make it a block element

Comment: Hey thanks for all you answers! Seems like i have a lot of points and some badges now, which is cool:-)Thanks for the links to the other posts! the pictures are just screenshots, made with screentool - i should try height with vh the next time. and also the block element solution. Sometimes it's just a little bit confusing, but i guess it get's easier with more experience and exposure to problems.